# datatable created in button one sent to button 2

Tags: c#, asp.net

my question is, if it is possible that the button_2 can call/use the data save in the datatable create in button_1. let say

```
void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some code to fill the datatable
}
```

now button 1 code has been done and it works, the only problem i have is i have no idea how to send de datatable from button_1 to button_2 this way button_2 can use the same data store in the datatable, by the way i am using C#, asp.net, and NOT using Visual Studio.

Comment: How large is the dataset you are retrieving in Button1_Click?

Comment: can vary from 36 to 500 or more elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state that the data is fetched in the event handler for `Button1` and it should be available in the event handler from `Button2`, you will have to persist the datatable in way so that it survives post backs.

There are several possibilities:

- Viewstate (as long as the object is `Serializable`, for `DataTable` it seems to work)
- Session (if you use sessions)
- Application scope (Application["yourKeyName"] = dbTable;)
- Static member of suitable class
- Server cache

Or, if the database operation to fetch the data is not "heavy" you could just load it from there when you need it.

For more reading regarding state management, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

**Edit**: To give you a more specific recommendation. Try storing the `DataTable` in the Session, like this

```
Session["preBuiltDataTable"] = theTable;
```

at the end of Button1_Click. Then get a reference to it using

```
DataTable tableFromB1Click = Session["preBuiltDataTable"] as DataTable;
if (tableFromB1Click != null)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

in Button2_Click.

Comment: thank you very much, you were right, the previus answer did not work, but this one works perfect

Answer (score 1):

Declare your DataTable outside your function

```
DataTable _myDataTable = new DataTable

void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some code to fill the datatable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to think about the flow. if the two button does the same thing, then why you need two button ?

if Two button does different work, but with same data then you can do like this.  you can store the datatable in memory. and access it.

```
   DataTable _myDataTable = new DataTable();

   //get Method

    public DataTable FillDatatable(DataTable _myDataTable)
    {
    return _myDataTable;
    }
```

in button2 Click, you check for its nullity. like this .

```
if(_myDataTable !=NULL)
{
  If(_myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 ) 
   //then do some fun  with that data 
}
```

Comment: @JUAN This cannot work between different postbacks. See my updated answer (soon...) for recommendatio of how to proceed.

Comment: @user1429080 you right this didn't,  i thought i did, but no, thaks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function [SaveDataTable(DataTable dt)] for data storage which accepts DataTable as parameter and call it from both button1 & button2 click function.

Hope this helps you. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 function suppose

```
public void fgh()
 {
    //write down your database code such as
    using(con=new SqlConnection(your connection string))
    { 
      cnn=new SqlCommand( your sql command);
      cnn.Connection=con;
      using(ds=new Dataset())
        {
          con.Open();
          da.Fill(ds);
       }
  }
}
```

now you have the function, call amongs the different button.

Comment: Since when C# is a full lowercase language? Doesn't your keyboard have a `Shift` key?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the DataTable to the ViewState such as

```
protected void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["DT"] = dt;              // dt is the DataTable
}
```

use the datatable as follows:

```
protected void Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)ViewState["DT"];              // dt is the DataTable
}
```